# I have a Collapsing toolbar and nested scroll view, I cant make it work

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.RestaurantMenuActivity">


    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolMenuBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/red"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/rest_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:src="@drawable/restaurant_image"
                />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


            <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="450dp">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerViewRestaurantMenu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                 />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutProceedToCart"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:visibility="invisible">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnProceedToCart"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/red"
                    android:text="Proceed to Cart"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

            </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/progressMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <ProgressBar
            android:theme="@style/CircularProgress"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is the Xml file, and I have a collapsing toolbar and a nested scroll view, but it isn't working, when I scroll the page the collapsing toolbar isn't working.
I have an image in the collapsing toolbar and a recycler view in the nested scroll view, when I scroll the recycle view the image view should collapse. But that isn't happening and is acting like a normal thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a recycler view as only child of nested scroll view is a bad practice since you are essentially taking away the one powerful aspect of recyclerview this way. Instead make the rest of the layout a part of nested layout as well and make recycler view `android:nestedScrollingEnabled=false`

After that add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to nested scroll view.

Edit:-

Try adding toolbar inside collapsingToolbar with

```
app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

Since collapsing toolbar is a frame layout you may have to adjust some margins to make it look like what you have right now

Comment: I edited the qn with latest changes, still it isn't working @RahulRawat

Comment: Put the collapsing toolbar layout inside app bar layout

Comment: Yes it is. It is scrolling without collapsing

Comment: Can you once try to remove the toolbar while putting collapsing toolbar inside appbarlayout and see if that works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234758/discussion-between-rahul-rawat-and-yazhini).